# Define POST or GET for a route

Tags: plugin-development

Is there a way to define a route that can only receive POST data?
In Laravel you can do this:

```
Route::post('admin/content/{id}', 'ContentController@update');
```

Is there a way to do this with a Craft route?

Tried this to no avail:

```
'POST, newseventsapi/v1/login' => array('action' => 'api/Login')
```

Comment: Taking out the comma after POST seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Taking out the comma after POST seems to work

Correct.  A common is only needed if you want to allow multiple HTTP methods like `POST,PUT`.

Here's the Yii documentation on the topic: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#http-methods